# "Êtes-vous véhiculé" meaning

Tags: sens

What does someone mean if they ask "Êtes-vous véhiculé ?". I was asked this question in the context of an interview and could not figure out if it meant if I can drive or if I own a car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit (after having seen @XouDo's comment).

The interviewer wanted to know if you (roughly) own a car. I guess that, theoretically speaking, you may answer that you could also rent one, use your parent's or have your brother/sister/someone other drop and pick you up too.

See an example of use in the context of recruitment here: https://www.cvwizard.fr/conseils/vehicule-cv

Comment: Yes roughly. You could also rent one, use your parent's or have your brother drop and pick you up too.

Comment: Est-ce que [_Larousse en ligne_](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/v%C3%A9hiculer/81269) se trompe quand il dit « En Afrique... » ?